# How can I get line numbers in TexWorks?

Tags: texworks

I opened up a file of mine in TexWorks. There were no line numbers. So, I navigated to `Edit > Preferences` and checked the line numbers box.

[image: TexWorks_preferences_menu]

Oddly enough, if I open up a new empty document, line numbers are displayed for the new document. However, there are no line numbers in my existing document. I have tried closing TexWorks, restarting it, and reopening my document. However, anytime I open my document instead of creating a new one, line numbers fail to display.

[image: new doc and old doc]

Any thoughts?

I'm running Windows 10 Home Edition

[image: tex works version]

Comment: I can't check on my own, but as far as I remember, you have also an option within format. That said, lines should appear when you restart, provided of course that you saved your preferences.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 9):

In menu <kbd>Edit</kbd> → <kbd>Preferences</kbd> → <kbd>☑ Lines numbers</kbd>  you set the default behavior for *new* or *unkown* documents, but you can change the settings only *for the actually edited* document in menu <kbd>Format</kbd> → <kbd>Lines numbers</kbd> (see image below).

This will change the behavior of that file even if you close and open the file again, *while* it is in the Recent Files List, i.e., with <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>Open Recent</kbd> → <kbd>Clear Recent files</kbd> you will lost that individual settings of all your files, so the next time you open the file, you will see the default behavior set in the Preferences window.

[image: screen]

Answer (score 1):

This is a behaviour "by design" see open issue at https://github.com/TeXworks/texworks/issues/222

> "This is the current design. The Preferences items affect the state in
>   which **new windows** are opened, but do **not modify already-existing
>   windows;** for that, use the `Format` menu items in the window
>   concerned.
>
> I don't want to lose the ability to have per-window settings, as (in
>   my  experience) different options are appropriate for different kinds
>   of file. But I can imagine perhaps being "smart" about these window
>   options,  e.g., by recording for each window whether it is using the
>   default (in which  case a Preferences change would affect it
>   immediately) or if it has been explicitly set by the user (in which
>   case the user's setting will "stick"  even if Preferences are
>   changed).
>
> Along with this, we should remember these per-window options across
>   the closing  and re-opening of a file." Original comment by
>   jfkth...@gmail.com on 12 Nov 2009 at 10:34

Personal use suggests the tick box is for a new file whilst existing files generally "remember" their setting from past file history so You need to toggle "off" or "on" **each windowed file** prior to closing.

To speed this task up you can set a shortcut (Authors suggestion is to set F4 to line_numbers) see the manual at https://github.com/TeXworks/manual

Answer (score 0):

if you wanted it to be done for reviewing purposes within the document, you could also use this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers
```

For more variation, [refer here](https://texblog.org/2012/02/08/adding-line-numbers-to-documents/)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that affects the exported `.pdf` (output), not the editor.

Comment: Indeed it does. As it is often the need to have line numbers within your pdf, I mentioned it as an option here.

Comment: Also please don't mind me wondering, but it there are a specific reason you are using TexWorks? I've been using Latex for years, and my personal favorite editor is TexStudio, really convenient for writing/editing if you want to use as much GUI for customization/help in styling etc.